# angularjs - Reload all directives on page after dynamically updating them

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bunch of directives in an html page, let's say the directive is `<my-directive></my-directive>`. These directives are added or changed **outside of AngularJS**, e.g. a jQuery function will simply `append` a new `<my-directive></my-directive>` to the page.

Here's my question - after appending the new `<my-directive></my-directive>`, the directive doesn't actually do anything - it's just a tag without any functionality.

How can I force Angular to recognize that a new tag has been added? I've tried mucking around with scope.apply but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use your databindings to manipulate the view? E.g. `ng-repeat`

Comment: Not sure I understood the questions, but I have several directives loaded in different parts of the page, controlled by outside code that's not part of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for angulars `$compile` method:

```
myApp.directive('addonclick', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){   
            var html = attrs.addonclick; //or something else     
            element.on("click", function(){
                $(element).append($compile(html)(scope));
            })
        };
    };
});
```

EDIT:

Try getting the scope first:

```
var scope = angular.element("yourElement").scope();
```

Then get and call the compile service:

```
var compile = angular.element("yourElement").injector().get("$compile"); //or
var compile = angular.injector(["moduleName"]).get("$compile");
$("yourElement").append(compile("<my-directive/>")(scope));
```

Comment: Ok, but in this case, it's an AngularJS directive itself that's adding the code to the page. I want to add the div in a way that's completely separate from AngularJS, e.g. a regular ol' jquery "click" method will add the div.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, since you need the scope. I'm also not sure why you want to do that, why can't you create your own directive which adds the `my-directive` on click?...Maybe you should post a little more code to make that clear.

Comment: The reason I can't is because I don't control the part of the page that's adding the code, I only control the directives that appear on the page. But I can tell the other parts of the page what code to run to insert a new directive, or what code to run after inserting a directive.

Comment: The 2nd version of getting the `$compile` service does not work. It seems you have to include all of the dependency modules as well.